# BIGINT scalar function

Tags: t-sql

How to??
Create a scalar function that returns a bigint.
The function takes 2 inputs of bigint.
The function multiplies the inputs and returns the result.

Thank You,

Comment: Did you do any searching anywhere before asking this question here?

Comment: Yes I did.  Do you have any recommendation site I can take a look at.  Thank You,

Comment: How about Googling (or Binging, if you're so inclined) "tsql create function"?

Comment: Was this a homework assignment?  Why would you want to use a function to multiply 2 values instead of just multiplying them directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[testbigint]
(
    @int1 bigint,
    @int2 bigint
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @returnVal bigint

    set @returnVal =  @int1* @int2

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @returnVal

END
```

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables saw it and it is now fixed. :)

Comment: @bluefeet (: Thank you so much. I am new with using BIGINT. Thank you again.  I need to wait 5mins to 'accept' your Answer.

Comment: @Kombucha - I know I'm going to come off as a complete jerk, but this has *nothing* to do with the data type; this is about as simple as a function as you could create.  Still, +1 to bluefeet for being helpful.